# Math operations in multiindiex dataframe with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multiindex `df`:

```
                    created_at          2020-06-29                                       2020-07-06
                                        sales   orders  last_sales      differennce      sales  orders  last_sales      differennce

group               category            10      10      10              0                10      10      20             50  
A                   a1
                    a2
                    a3
B                   a1                  ...     ...     ...            ...               ...     ...     ...
                    a2
                    a3
all                 Total               100     100     100            0                 150     150     150            0
```

I am trying to calculate the `difference` in `all & Total` indexes which is `((sales / last_sales) -1) * 100` where `created_at` is `2020-06-29 to 2021-07-19`.

I tried:

```
df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'difference')] = 
((df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'sales')] / 
df.loc[('all','Total'),:'2021-07-19','last_sales']) - 1) * 100
```

But I get an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I seem to can't select the `created_at` range that I want, but this works:

```
df.loc[:,:'2021-07-19'] # returning the dates I want, from first to selected
```

But when I try to select the one row it breaks:

```
df_out.loc[:,(:'2021-07-19','sales')] # SyntaxError: invalid syntax

&

df_out.loc[:,:'2021-07-19','sales'] # IndexError: list index out of range
```

How I could select all of the rows where `group = all`, `category = Total` and dates are from `2020-06-29 to 2020-07-19`?

I also tried:

```
df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'difference')] = 
((df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'sales')] / 
df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'last_sales')]) - 1) * 100 # slice(None) instead of date
```

But this throws me `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` because there are `last_sales = 0` for dates above `2021-07-19`. Maybe there is other way of dealing with the `0s`? I tried adding `1` like so `df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'last_sales')]+1) - 1) * 100` but I still get the same error.

Example `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'B',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'all',
  19: 'all'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Amazon',
  1: 'Apple',
  2: 'Facebook',
  3: 'Google',
  4: 'Netflix',
  5: 'Tesla',
  6: 'Total',
  7: 'Uber',
  8: 'total',
  9: 'Amazon',
  10: 'Apple',
  11: 'Facebook',
  12: 'Google',
  13: 'Netflix',
  14: 'Tesla',
  15: 'Total',
  16: 'Uber',
  17: 'total',
  18: 'Total',
  19: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 195.0,
  1: 61.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 61.0,
  4: 37.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 954.0,
  7: 4.0,
  8: 477.0,
  9: 50.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 75.0,
  12: 43.0,
  13: 17.0,
  14: 14.0,
  15: 504.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 252.0,
  18: 2916.0,
  19: 2916.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 1268.85,
  1: 18274.385000000002,
  2: 19722.65,
  3: 55547.255,
  4: 15323.800000000001,
  5: 1688.6749999999997,
  6: 227463.23,
  7: 1906.0,
  8: 113731.615,
  9: 3219.6499999999996,
  10: 15852.060000000001,
  11: 17743.7,
  12: 37795.15,
  13: 5918.5,
  14: 1708.75,
  15: 166349.64,
  16: 937.01,
  17: 83174.82,
  18: 787625.7400000001,
  19: 787625.7400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 26.0,
  1: 39.0,
  2: 79.0,
  3: 49.0,
  4: 10.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 436.0,
  7: 5.0,
  8: 218.0,
  9: 89.0,
  10: 34.0,
  11: 133.0,
  12: 66.0,
  13: 21.0,
  14: 20.0,
  15: 732.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 366.0,
  18: 2336.0,
  19: 2336.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 3978.15,
  1: 12138.96,
  2: 19084.175,
  3: 40033.46000000001,
  4: 4280.15,
  5: 1495.1,
  6: 165548.29,
  7: 1764.15,
  8: 82774.145,
  9: 8314.92,
  10: 12776.649999999996,
  11: 28048.075,
  12: 55104.21000000002,
  13: 6962.844999999999,
  14: 3053.2000000000003,
  15: 231049.11000000002,
  16: 1264.655,
  17: 115524.55500000001,
  18: 793194.8000000002,
  19: 793194.8000000002},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 96.0,
  1: 56.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 44.0,
  4: 34.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 716.0,
  7: 9.0,
  8: 358.0,
  9: 101.0,
  10: 22.0,
  11: 120.0,
  12: 40.0,
  13: 13.0,
  14: 8.0,
  15: 610.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 305.0,
  18: 2652.0,
  19: 2652.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 5194.95,
  1: 19102.219999999994,
  2: 22796.420000000002,
  3: 30853.115,
  4: 11461.25,
  5: 992.6,
  6: 188143.41,
  7: 3671.15,
  8: 94071.705,
  9: 6022.299999999998,
  10: 7373.6,
  11: 33514.0,
  12: 35943.45,
  13: 4749.000000000001,
  14: 902.01,
  15: 177707.32,
  16: 349.3,
  17: 88853.66,
  18: 731701.46,
  19: 731701.46},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 45.0,
  1: 47.0,
  2: 87.0,
  3: 45.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 8.0,
  6: 494.0,
  7: 2.0,
  8: 247.0,
  9: 81.0,
  10: 36.0,
  11: 143.0,
  12: 56.0,
  13: 9.0,
  14: 9.0,
  15: 670.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 335.0,
  18: 2328.0,
  19: 2328.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 7556.414999999998,
  1: 14985.05,
  2: 16790.899999999998,
  3: 36202.729999999996,
  4: 4024.97,
  5: 1034.45,
  6: 163960.32999999996,
  7: 1385.65,
  8: 81980.16499999998,
  9: 5600.544999999999,
  10: 11209.92,
  11: 32832.61,
  12: 42137.44500000001,
  13: 3885.1499999999996,
  14: 1191.5,
  15: 194912.34000000003,
  16: 599.0,
  17: 97456.17000000001,
  18: 717745.3400000001,
  19: 717745.3400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

Comment: Can you provide an easy copy and paste dataframe, especially with MultiIndex it's better to provide the data as `pd.DataFrame..`

Comment: Is the typo in `differennce` also present in your data?

Comment: Added an example `df` with the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pd.IndexSlice` and we need to slice on `pd.Timestamp` since your first level columns is of type datetime:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
sales = df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'sales')].droplevel(level=1)
last_sales = df.loc[('all','Total'), :pd.Timestamp("2021-07-07")].loc[idx[:, "last_sales"]]

df.loc[('all','Total'),(slice(None),'difference')] = sales.div(last_sales).sub(1).mul(100).to_numpy()
```

```
               2020-06-29 00:00:00                      2020-07-06 00:00:00                      2021-06-28 00:00:00                      2021-07-07 00:00:00                     
                        last_sales     sales difference          last_sales     sales difference          last_sales     sales difference          last_sales     sales difference
group category                                                                                                                                                                    
A     Amazon                195.00   1268.85       0.00               26.00   3978.15       0.00               96.00   5194.95       0.00               45.00   7556.41       0.00
      Apple                  61.00  18274.39       0.00               39.00  12138.96       0.00               56.00  19102.22       0.00               47.00  14985.05       0.00
      Facebook              106.00  19722.65       0.00               79.00  19084.17       0.00              106.00  22796.42       0.00               87.00  16790.90       0.00
      Google                 61.00  55547.25       0.00               49.00  40033.46       0.00               44.00  30853.12       0.00               45.00  36202.73       0.00
      Netflix                37.00  15323.80       0.00               10.00   4280.15       0.00               34.00  11461.25       0.00               13.00   4024.97       0.00
      Tesla                  13.00   1688.67       0.00               10.00   1495.10       0.00               13.00    992.60       0.00                8.00   1034.45       0.00
      Total                 954.00 227463.23       0.00              436.00 165548.29       0.00              716.00 188143.41       0.00              494.00 163960.33       0.00
      Uber                    4.00   1906.00       0.00                5.00   1764.15       0.00                9.00   3671.15       0.00                2.00   1385.65       0.00
      total                 477.00 113731.62       0.00              218.00  82774.15       0.00              358.00  94071.71       0.00              247.00  81980.16       0.00
B     Amazon                 50.00   3219.65       0.00               89.00   8314.92       0.00              101.00   6022.30       0.00               81.00   5600.54       0.00
      Apple                  50.00  15852.06       0.00               34.00  12776.65       0.00               22.00   7373.60       0.00               36.00  11209.92       0.00
      Facebook               75.00  17743.70       0.00              133.00  28048.08       0.00              120.00  33514.00       0.00              143.00  32832.61       0.00
      Google                 43.00  37795.15       0.00               66.00  55104.21       0.00               40.00  35943.45       0.00               56.00  42137.45       0.00
      Netflix                17.00   5918.50       0.00               21.00   6962.84       0.00               13.00   4749.00       0.00                9.00   3885.15       0.00
      Tesla                  14.00   1708.75       0.00               20.00   3053.20       0.00                8.00    902.01       0.00                9.00   1191.50       0.00
      Total                 504.00 166349.64       0.00              732.00 231049.11       0.00              610.00 177707.32       0.00              670.00 194912.34       0.00
      Uber                    3.00    937.01       0.00                3.00   1264.65       0.00                1.00    349.30       0.00                1.00    599.00       0.00
      total                 252.00  83174.82       0.00              366.00 115524.56       0.00              305.00  88853.66       0.00              335.00  97456.17       0.00
all   Total                2916.00 787625.74   26910.48             2336.00 793194.80   33855.26             2652.00 731701.46   27490.55             2328.00 717745.34   30730.99
      total                2916.00 787625.74       0.00             2336.00 793194.80       0.00             2652.00 731701.46       0.00             2328.00 717745.34       0.00
```

Comment: Had to use `sales.div(last_sales.add(1).sub(1).mul(100).to_numpy()` to still deal with `0`, thank you!